# Add dynamic text box on each image pop-up in the page for image description

Tags: jquery, html, css, sql

I am working on this page.

http://ilfsamanvay.org/photos.php

I wish to add image description in all the images after the On-click pop-up is done.

Comment: What library are you using at the moment, if any?

Comment: I can share the source code of the page if you want?

Comment: Sure thing, that will help.

Comment: Can you provide an email id? I can send you the associated html,css, php and js files.

Comment: I am relatively new to this network so don't know how to post

Comment: Post the relative html, CSS, and JS

Comment: I played with your HTML a little bit, try code from my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with code bellow:

```
<a href="images/day 1/day1_002.jpg" rel="articles[gallery1]" title="test">
    <img src="images/day 1/day1_002.jpg" height="110" width="133" alt="Gallery">
</a>
```

Since you are using PrettyPhoto plugin, only thing you need to add is `title` within `a` HTML tag. It does not look that nice, but you can play with CSS.

Comment: Great, mark it as answered/vote up. That's how Stack Overflow works :) Just mentioning sine you are new here.